# SSL certificates for connection over TCP/IP

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, tcp, jsmpp

I have a Java application which communicates with a Server and exchanges short messages over SMPP connection over TCP/IP. I want to add SSL security to make the short messages secured. I am using JSMPP (Java implementation of SMPP). I want answers to following points:

1. Where should I add SSL certificates in the application running machine (client)? Probably I should add them to JVM. Please confirm.
2. I have server implementation on another machine in java which run and waits for TCP/IP connection. Where should I add the certificates on server machine ?
3. Do I need to change the code or the JVM will add security to the existing code ?
4. Where can I find a free trial SSL certificates ?

I am using Java 1.6 and JSMPP 2.1.0

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Where should I add SSL certificates in the application running machine (client)?
> Probably I should add them to JVM. Please confirm.
>
> I have server implementation on another machine in java which run and waits for TCP/IP connection. Where should I add the certificates on server machine ?

You need to generate SSL certificates by your own for your server at server side only.

Store SSL certificates at server side Java directory.

> Do I need to change the code or the JVM will add security to the existing code ?

code should be changed as you will have to connect to secured server (https) and import certificates accordingly.

> Where can I find a free trial SSL certificates ?

As said in 1st answer, you need to generate certificate by your own and should no rely on free SSL certificates. (I doubt even you can find and import free certificates for your site).

Comment: Code may or may not need to be changed depending on the SMPP package. You can use free SSL certificates.

Comment: For that you need to understand how those are created and also, rely on third party certificates even though you can create your own. This is indeed risky for production environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use StartSSL to generate free SSL certificates:
https://www.startssl.com/